# Error while trying to read a file

Tags: java, spring, file, maven

In my Java/Maven application, I'm trying to read some files that is in resources folder. I just can read this files when execute the application in Eclipse, but when I try to run the application with the command bellow I get a Nullpointer because the file is not found.

```
java -Dserver.port=$PORT -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar my-war.war
```

I'm reading the file with this command:

```
String string = new String(
            Files.readAllBytes(
                    Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("fileFolder/file.html").toURI())));
```

Comment: Tell me: what does ClassLoader.getSystemResource do?

Comment: Get the url of the resource with the name that you pass in parameter

Comment: ... *from the system class loader* which your class might not be in.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the app works when I run from IDE. But, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: First try `SomeClassInYourProject.class.getClassLoader().getResource(...)`

Comment: Yes, I try. But I get the same result

Comment: Then my next suspect is: What do you think happens when you use `Paths.get` or `File.readAllBytes` on something that's not a file? (I don't know what happens, but apparently it doesn't work)

Comment: if the resource is not found then Paths.get throws  java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException, and is exactly what is happening. I check the .war file and the files are there

Comment: No, the files are not in the .war file. The .war entries, which are usually thought of as files but aren't actually files until you extract them, are in the .war file.

Comment: Understood. But, even so, I think that this approach would work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124174/discussion-between-immibis-and-douglas-gabriel).

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved changing the way that I read the resource:

```
IOUtils.toString((new ClassPathResource("fileFolder/file.html").getInputStream()));
```

because the resources when in .war not are treated as files, so read them as file will throw an exception